# IdentityServer3 - how to get partial identity in PreAuthenticateAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver3

Question is quite self-describing. There is method:

```
await this.owinContext.Environment.GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync();
```

But in `PreAuthenticateAsync` method it gets `null` result. As a way how to achieve partial identity I use redirect to one of my controllers and back, but is there better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the method name implies, this hits before any authentication takes place, so it won't have any partial login to give you. You should rather make that call in PostAuthenticateAsync which will hit after any authentication step and where you can create context.AuthenticateResult using an appropriate constructor that will either give you a new partial redirect or full result.

Comment: I needed to work with claims before Auth itself, I solved it other way but I agree your answer is correct